# Reset awk field separator

Tags: awk

On my local system, it appears that the configuration for awk has somehow been changed.

Running the following command:

```
echo "Hi there" | awk '{print $2}'
```

On my machine this prints:

```
Hi there
```

And on my development server it prints:

```
there
```

I am sure that at some point my local machine would behave the same as my server - i.e. it should print only the second word.

How do I reset the awk field separator back to its default (which according to [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html) is a sequence of spaces)?

Comment: Yeah, no... there's... there's no way it could possibly have the former output. Unless it's not awk.

Comment: Apologies. I was actually running this on my local system:
echo "Hi there" | awk "{print $2}"
Hadn't realised that double quotes and single quotes were used differently.

Comment: Indeed. Double quotes allow variable substitution, which would cause `$2` to collapse to nothing, printing the whole line.

Comment: You might have done this: `echo Hi there | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: / Ignacio: I hope one of you will post an answer regarding double quotes - then Alex can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The field separator is set explicitly using

```
awk -F' ' '{ print $2; }'
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=" "; } { print $2; }'
```